# How to allow guest users to view posts, without having to login

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to make Guests users i.e users that are not logged in to view some posts.

I have tried to add Guest Auth but it is not working. Also i will love to get the URL link to the post as slug instead of ID

E.g localhost:8000/news/1 should be localhost:8000/news/post-title

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\News;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $news= News::paginate(15);
        return view('categories.news',compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('news.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate

        $this->validate($request,[
            'subject'=>'required|min:10',
            'body' => 'required|min:20'
        ]);

        //store
        auth()->user()->news()->create($request->all());

        //redirect
        $news= News::paginate(15);
        return view('categories.news', compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\News  $news
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(News $news)
    {
        return view('news.single', compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\News  $news
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(News $news)
    {
        return view('news.edit', compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\News  $news
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, News $news)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->id !== $news->user_id){
            abort(401, "Please Login");
        }

        $this->validate($request,[
            'subject'=>'required|min:10',
            'body' => 'required|min:20'
        ]);

        $news->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('news.show', $news->id)->withMessage('News Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\News  $news
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(News $news)
    {   
        if(auth()->user()->id !== $news->user_id){
            abort(401, "Please Login");
        }

        $news->delete();

        $news= News::paginate(15);
        return view('categories.news', compact('news'));
    }
}
```

This is the single post blade that i will like guest users to be able to view.

```
<div class="main-body">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="main-body-content text-left">
                <h1 style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: 800;" class="post-title">{{$news->subject}}</h1>
                <h5>By <a href="">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></h5>
                <div class="post-body">
                    <p>{!! $news->body !!}</p>
                </div>
                @if(auth()->user()->id==$news->user_id)
                <div class="all-edit">
                <div class="post-body">
                    <a href="{{route('news.edit',$news->id)}}">(Edit)</a>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <form action="{{route('news.destroy',$news->id)}}" method="POST">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove this route from middleware of "auth".

Comment: Nothing understandable (